# Delay to a MOSFET switching

Tags: relay, sensor, switching, delay

[image]I have a very simply circuit which, when the sensing lines contact water, switches a relay. The circuit performs well on 12 to 15 VDC.

I want to add a delay of approximately 3 seconds to the circuit switching on. Off can be instant or with a similar delay, but off isn’t the important issue.

All advice is welcome.

Comment: A 3 second delay begs for an MCU.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a circuit similar to the one I made.

[image: Delay circuit]

When the button is pressed, the capacitor C3 starts charging through resistor R4 to approximately half input voltage. Once the voltage crosses Vth (Threshold voltage of MOSFET), the MOSFET will turn on causing the relay to turn on too.

Once the button is released, the capacitor will start discharging through R5 and the MOSFET will turn off once the voltage across C3 drops down below Vth.

I have attached an image of the output waveforms to help you understand better.

[image: Waveforms]

- Yellow represents the button state.
- Blue represents the voltage across C3.
- Pink represents Vds of transistor.

This is just a reference circuit and may require modifications to run properly in a practical application.
You can calculate the values of components according to your own requirements.